# Select query not returning properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have the following function

```
public function checkLogin($username, $password){
    
    $select_query = $this->connect()->prepare("SELECT `username` , `password` FROM `users` 
            WHERE `username` = :username AND `password` = :password");
$select_query->bindParam(':username', $username);
$select_query->bindParam(':password', $password);
try{
        $select_query->execute(); 
    } catch(Exception $ex) {
        echo "An Error occured while checking for username!\n"; //user friendly message
        logger($ex->getMessage());
    }
    return ($select_query->fetchColumn() > 0) ? true : false;
}
```

Which always returns nothing when $username is test and $password is password, and when I just run the sql from phpMyAdmin it gives the correct result. This is what I ran on phpMyAdmin

```
SELECT  `username` ,  `password` 
FROM  `users` 
WHERE  `username` =  'test'
AND  `password` =  'password'
```

The result returned being 1 user which is correct.

Comment: WHAT is logger($ex->getMessage()) displaying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify the type of the parameters:

```
$select_query->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$select_query->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: @Mehran if you tried this suggestion and it didn't work. My best bet is that you have a problem with the same name of fields and parameters. Try to change their names. like `:usern` and `:userpass` and see what happen.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `bindValue` instead of bindParam

```
$select_query->bindValue(':username', $username);
$select_query->bindValue(':password', $password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a second look at your sql statement:

```
"SELECT `username`, `password`
FROM `users` 
WHERE `username` = :username AND `password` = :password"
```

Because you are searching on string data types, you need to wrap your :username and :password slugs in single quotes. Try that and it should do the trick.

Comment: still won't work, I tried that while using INSERTING and it would just insert ':password' and ':username' without replacing it.